CalendarDatePicker not showing Avalonia
Avalonia 11.0.10
Citrus.Avalonia 2.1.1
Material.Avalonia 3.5.0
For the UI I use Citrus.Avalonia. I encountered a problem that CalendarDatePicker does not show the calendar when I click on the button.

And Calendar control simply does not appear in the window.
When I use Material.Avalonia library, CalendarDatePicker does not show anything, even textbox is not displayed. But Calendar Control works fine.
If I do not use third-party libraries for the user interface, then CalendarDatePicker works fine (but I need to use libraries for UI).
I thought that perhaps the problem was with the version of the libraries. But changing the version did not help.
What could be the problem?
<CalendarDatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate}" DisplayDateEnd="{Binding DateEnd}" DisplayDateStart="{Binding DateStart}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChangesEnable}"/>

